# A list of N different positive integers. There are some two integers that had a product divisible by 15. What is the smallest value of N

Tags: combinatorics

Swati made a list of N different positive integers, each strictly less than 1000. Swati told her friend Roma what the value of N was, and based on this value, Roma knew that there were some two integers in Swati's list that had a product divisible by 15. What is the smallest value that N could have been

Comment: Help please. I want answer in 10 mins (if u can)

Comment: -1. Brain [still not engaged](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/241273) + outrageous comment = "winning" combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among, $1$ to $999,$ there are $[\frac{999}5]=199$ multiples of 5.

So, there are $999-199=800$ positive integers $<1000$ which are not  multiple of $5.$

So, if we take $N\ge800+1=801,$ the set will contain at least one multiple of $5.$

Similarly, for $N\ge999-\frac{999}3+1=667,$ the set will contain at least one multiple of $3$

So, if we take $N=max(801,667)=801,$ we shall definitely find at least one multiple of  $5$ and of $3$.

Comment: @Pambos, we need two integers whose product is divisible by $15,$  not a single element to be multiple of $15$. Btw, how have you reached at $861?$

Comment: Sorry, I will delete my comment. 861 was a typo and the comment was a mistake (I didn't understand the question).

Comment: @chndn, welcome. But don't forget to avoid phrases like "I want answer in 10 mins (if u can)".